# When does std::is_convertible consider primitive types convertible?

Tags: c++, primitive-types

Using [std::is_convertible](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible):

```
bool i2c = std::is_convertible<int, char>::value;
bool c2i = std::is_convertible<char, int>::value;
bool f2i = std::is_convertible<float, int>::value;

std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << i2c << '\n';  //prints true
std::cout << c2i << '\n';  //prints true
std::cout << f2i << '\n';  //prints true
```

I couldn't get why the output had to be `true` for all the above cases, when they appeared to be in-convertible (*type conversions that can cause loss of precision*). Or are we not supposed to compare the primitive types using `std::is_convertible`?

Comment: But they are all convertible... you can cast an `int` to a `char` or a `float` to an `int` if you want to.  Why do you think you can't?

Comment: When they are convertible. ;)

Comment: @SauravSahu Because it is convertible

Comment: @GuyGreer - you don't need a **cast** for any of those conversions. They can all be done implicitly.

Comment: @SauravSahu Given `double d = 0; char c = d;`, does your compiler give you an error? If so, what does the error say? If not, why do you think `double` cannot be converted to `char`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The page linked states:

> If the return statement in the imaginary function definition `{ return std::declval<From>(); }` is well-formed, (that is, if `std::declval<From>()` can be converted **using implicit conversion**), provides the member constant value equal to true.

All of the types mentioned are implicitly convertible (although the compiler may issue a warning), ie:

```
float f = 0.8f
int i = f; // Legal implicit conversion.
```

Is perfectly legal and well formed. So `std::is_convertible<float, int>::value` will be true. The same holds for the remainder of the listed comparisons.